# Sci-fi series about a mercenary with a spaceship with AI

Tags: story-identification, books

It's a book series about a guy that has a spaceship and the ship has AI and he travels all over doing odd jobs. There's one book with Lucky Jack in the title I think.  I'm pretty sure he's hired to steal the ship but he keeps it.  The ship is smart, like it's pointed out that it's no ordinary AI. It's basically he's a mercenary with an AI spaceship that can do it all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd suggest this is the *Jon and Lobo* series by Mark L. van Name

> Jon Moore: A nanotech-enhanced warrior who wants nothing more than a quiet life and a way back to his strange home world.
>
> Lobo: An AI-enhanced Predator-Class Assault Vehicle, a mobile fortress equipped for any environment from the seabed to interstellar space.
>
> <sup>[**Goodreads**](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/385460.One_Jump_Ahead)</sup>

The second book in the series is *Slanted Jack*

> Jon and Lobo Series @ [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_L._Van_Name#Novels)
>
> - One Jump Ahead (June 2007) ISBN 978-1-4165-2085-6
> - Slanted Jack (July 2008) ISBN 978-1-4165-5549-0
> - Overthrowing Heaven (June 2009) ISBN 978-1-4391-3267-8
> - Children No More (August 2010) ISBN 978-1-4391-3365-1
> - No Going Back (May 2012) ISBN 978-1-4516-3810-3

Comment: Thank you!! Thats exactly it! I could not remember to save my life